# How to use ApproximateTime in python

Tags: ros, python, approximatetime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to synchronize (approximately since the stamps of the topics are different) 4 topics.

I have looked at the ApproximateTime example here: http://answers.ros.org/question/60903/timesynchronizer-callback-problem/

But how to do it in python? I have looked at the Python API (http://docs.ros.org/api/message_filters/html/python/) for message filters, but it says nothing about approximatetime.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81126/how-to-use-approximatetime-in-python/) by [whiterose](https://answers.ros.org/users/349/whiterose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2013-09-19

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ananthakrishnan](https://answers.ros.org/users/24606/ananthakrishnan/) on 2015-10-18**:
Here 10 is the size of queue and 1 is the time in sec to consider for aprox:

```
one = message_filters.Subscriber('robot0/sonar_0', Range)
two = message_filters.Subscriber('robot0/sonar_1', Range)
ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([one, two],10,1)
ts.registerCallback(callback)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ApproximateTime was added for python in indigo, and is documented in the [indigo version of the api docs](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/message_filters/html/python/).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2018-12-03**:
It seems that this kind of subscriber cannot be unregistered, can you confirm?

**Comment by [ljburtz](https://answers.ros.org/users/37226/ljburtz/) on 2021-05-28**:
you can unsubscribe by iterating over each message_filter's subscription

Assuming you subscribed like this:

```
self.subs = [message_filters.Subscriber(topic, mtype) for topic, mtype in zip(self.topics, self.types)]
self.ts = message_filters.ApproximateTimeSynchronizer(
            self.subs,
            5,  # queue size
            0.2,
            allow_headerless=False
)  
self.ts.registerCallback(self.cb_logger)
```

You can unsubscribe like this:

```
for sub in self.subs:
            sub.sub.unregister()
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just in case someone has some trouble getting going with this, here's an example:

```
from message_filters import ApproximateTimeSynchronizer, Subscriber

def gotimage(image, camerainfo):
    assert image.header.stamp == camerainfo.header.stamp
    print "got an Image and CameraInfo"

image_sub = Subscriber("/wide_stereo/left/image_rect_color", sensor_msgs.msg.Image)
camera_sub = Subscriber("/wide_stereo/left/camera_info", sensor_msgs.msg.CameraInfo)

ats = ApproximateTimeSynchronizer([image_sub, camera_sub], queue_size=5, slop=0.1))
ats.registerCallback(gotimage)
```

I adapted this from the [docs](http://docs.ros.org/api/message_filters/html/python/).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-11-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1